# How does this templated code compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling to understand how this compiles:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct A { ... };

struct B {
  template <class T>
  using C = A<T, B>;
  ...
};
```

How can I pass 'B' as a template argument to 'A' within the definition of 'B' - that is, 'B' is not yet fully defined...

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: It's explicitly allowed by C++. B doesn't need to be fully defined unless it's used inside `A` as a value type.

Comment: Don't post code that won't compile and then tell us it compiles.  In these cases, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Replace the ellipses by `/* ... */` and you have a MCVE or something trivially close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line you’re concerned about, `B` is declared as an “incomplete type.”  Here’s a simpler example:

```
struct foo {
  foo *p;
};
```

You can also declare an incomplete type with a statement like `struct foo;`.  This doesn’t give the compiler enough information to let you create a `foo` or store a `foo` within another structure, but it does let you use the name in contexts where knowing that `foo` is the name of a type is enough.  An example:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo;
using foovector = std::vector<foo>; // Legal.
// foovector v(4); // Invalid.
```

If you uncomment the final line and try to compile, you’ll get a bunch of error messages saying that `foo` is an incomplete type.  The compiler can’t create a `vector` of `foo` because it doesn’t know the size of a `foo`, or therefore how much memory to allocate.  But give the type a complete definition and it works:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo;
using foovector = std::vector<foo>; // Legal.

struct foo {
  foo *p;
};

foovector v(4); // Now this works.
```